# Is anyone testing Mono-Touch?

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios

Is anyone on the site in the beta for [MonoTouch](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch)?  What issues have you been seeing with it?

I personally have found it a very nice little system and have just made a small test app with it.  The test app seems to startup slowly, but it works on my device so I am happy to be using C# on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the monotouch mailing list you will find lots of useful information.

I for one found a couple of issues, mainly with the Interface Builder generating the C# code.

another one was an issue with MapKit where the app crashes.

Constant conversation on issues and ways to work around it are in the list and in #monotouch on the GIMP irc network.

Answer (score 0):

Monotouch:
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/conqueror/id606796149?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/conqueror-for-ipad/id606816778?mt=8&uo=44

It's also using ZXing.Net.Mobile.MonoTouch

I just loved it.
I don't know much about beta version. I bought the professional license and I am happy with that. It's impressive how fast I can get things running on C#. These 2 games are retina ready and optimized for iPhone 5.